# smalltalk: how to select the first n items from a collection

Tags: lambda, indexing, closures, smalltalk

I have an collection c, I basically want to split the collection into two parts: the first n items into one list and the rest to another. Obviously, I can use do:, but is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about the other dialects but [pharo](/questions/tagged/pharo) has this useful methods: `first:` `last:` `allButFirst:` `allButLast:`

So you can do something like:

```
firstPart := c first: 10.
secondPart := c allButFirst: 10
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `copyFrom: to:`.

For example:

```
firstTen := myCollection copyFrom: 1 to: 10.
```

Comment: You can even use: `firstTen := myCollection first: 10`.